# Restricted group local administrators can RDP into DC

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, remote-desktop, user-permissions

I have added restricted groups to my Desktops OU and this adds the "Local Admins" security group to the Local Administrators group on workstations in that OU. The issue is, that after this GPO is applied, regular user accounts can RDP "INTO THE DOMAIN CONTROLLER" I have confirmed that this is the offending GPO and there are no other settings in this GPO; it's only purpose is to apply that one restricted group.

The group does get applied to the workstations and does work as expected except for this one issue. Even a gpresult /z doesn't mention that GPO anywhere when ran on the DC but does on the workstations.

The "Desktops" OU contains the "Local Admins" GPO. The Domain controller is in the "Domain COntrollers" OU.

[OU Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZDEq.png)

[Restricted Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH1RJ.png)

**"gpresult /scope computer /r" of Workstation:**

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
c 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Created on 04/30/2016 at 1:29:28 PM



RSOP data for DOMAIN\John.Doe on WORKSTATION : Logging Mode
-----------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  10.0.10586
Site Name:                   Default-First-Site-Name
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\John.Doe
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=WORKSTATION,OU=Mobile-Devices,DC=DOMAIN,DC=info
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 04/30/2016 at 12:07:55 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      DOMAINCONTROLLER.DOMAIN.info
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        DOMAIN
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Computer GPO
        Local Admin GPO
        Remote Management
        PSTools
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        WORKSTATION$
        Domain Computers
        Authentication authority asserted identity
        System Mandatory Level
```

**"gpresult /scope computer /r" of DC:**

```
    Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
c 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Created on 4/30/2016 at 1:22:52 PM



RSOP data for DOMAIN\John.Doe on DOMAINCONTROLLER : Logging Mode
----------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Primary Domain Controller
OS Version:                  6.2.9200
Site Name:                   Default-First-Site-Name
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\John.Doe
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=DOMAINCONTROLLER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=DOMAIN,DC=info
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 4/30/2016 at 1:20:57 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      DOMAINCONTROLLER.DOMAIN.info
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        DOMAIN
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Default Domain Controllers Policy
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        Certificate Service DCOM Access
        BUILTIN\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access
        BUILTIN\Users
        Windows Authorization Access Group
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        DOMAINCONTROLLER$
        Domain Controllers
        NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS
        Authentication authority asserted identity
        Denied RODC Password Replication Group
        RAS and IAS Servers
        Cert Publishers
        System Mandatory Level
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your restricted group settings shown that Local admins group is member of "Administrators" group which is domain group. If you want them to be member of local administrator group, you need to configure "This group member of" setting to "BUILTIN\Administrators"

Comment: I updated the description. Did that add the info you needed?

Comment: So, when adding the BUILTIN\Administrators, the Restricted Group automatically removes the BUILTIN\ from it. I definately selected the builtin group when setting that up.

Comment: But I have been thinking that it is selecting anything with "Administrators" as the group name; local or otherwise.

Comment: @Jedimaster0 you need not to choose, you need manually type it.

Comment: Well, I can't RDP into the DCs anymore. I'm signing off the workstation after a gpupdate. *crossing fingers*

Comment: Omg... I think you were right. I have been skipping over this because of what I read earlier. I can't believe it was that simple... Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Jedimaster0 glad I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

@Sentator14 was on the right track, but not quite there.

Your problem is that there is no such thing as a *local* Administrators group on domain controllers.  When a DC is promoted, the local SAM database goes away and AD becomes the only source of users and groups.  So by configuring a group policy to add a group to the `Administrators` group on a DC, you are effectively adding it to the **domain group** called `Administrators`.  It's not the same as the actual `Domain Admins` group, but it's still critical and quite highly privileged as you discovered.

You need to configure your GPO to not apply to the DCs, either by changing how you're doing inheritance or by using something like WMI filtering.

Comment: So, would you say that this tutorial is incorrect? It is one of many I have been using. I used server manager from my workstation and did select a local administrator when setting up the Restricted Group (not the domain one)

Comment: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Managing_local_groups_on_domain_members_via_GPO_restricted_groups